# Foreach Json Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have array, where get_# have random number. Need to `foreach` all items `[result][result][get_#RAND_NUM#]` and take `[id], [name]`.
Thanks! 
Array:

```
-[result]
--[result]

---[get_1]
----[id] = "1"
----[name] = "dog"

---[get_6]
----[id] = "53"
----[name] = "cat"
```

Comment: what problem have you faced? show your code

Comment: And what did you try to achieve this? As it stands right now, there is no question, just requirements.

Comment: i dont know how i can foreach random num, as like that: `foreach($res["result"]["result"]["get_????"] as $value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PHP manual the [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) makes an iteration over array or object. `foreach` provides `$key` and `$value` options. From this `$key` var you can get the random number you expect.

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable.

```
$data = ['result' => [
    'result' => [
        'get_1' => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'doc'],
        'get_6' => ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'cat'],
    ]
]];
$new_data = [];
foreach ($data['result']['result'] as $key => $val) {
    // If you want to get the random number uncomment the below line
    // $random_no = explode('_', $key)[1]; echo $random_no;
    echo "For key {$key}, id = {$val['id']} and name = {$val['name']} </br>";
    $new_data[] = ['id' => $val['id'], 'name' => $val['name']];
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($new_data);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/fE2RX)